# why is the following code not returning sum of all the array elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, javascript-objects, es6-promise

Below is the code, I want to return the sum of all the array elements, why is it not working. I know we don't need the Promise to achieve that but I would like to know how it can be done with a Promise.

```
const arr = [1, 5, 7, 8]; 
    function sumPromise(a, b) {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res(a + b);
    }, 1000);
  });
}
let res = arr.reduce(sumPromise);
res.then((a) => console.log(a));
```

output:[object Promise]8

Comment: then how can I get the sum of array elements using the above function that returns a promise

Comment: It was a question in an interview I gave, I couldn't understand how that can be done. We need to use the sumPromise function to solve the problem. I thought reduce might work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this will help

```js
const arr = [1, 5, 7, 8];

function sumPromise(a, b) {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      a.then(item => res(item + b))
    }, 1000);
  });
}

let res = arr.reduce(sumPromise, Promise.resolve(0));
res.then((a) => console.log(a));
```

Without changing sumPromise

```js
const arr = [1, 5, 7, 8];

function sumPromise(a, b) {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res(a + b);
    }, 1000);
  });
}

let res = arr.reduce(
  (a, b) => a.then(item => sumPromise(item, b)),
  Promise.resolve(0)
);
res.then(console.log);
```

Comment: This runs too fast. About 2 seconds instead of 4.

Comment: @Andy updated answer please check now

Comment: @Andy now correct ?

Comment: The last line can be shortened `res.then(console.log);`

Comment: @Jay hey, thanks a lot this is working. Can you pls share the other code which you submitted?

Comment: @Yus first is not proper but it will provide answer, second is your answer

Comment: @jay yeah, just wanted to see the other way this could be done. Thanks a ton for the response!

Answer (score 1):

```js
let total = 0;
const arr = [1, 5, 7, 8];

function sumPromise(a, b) {
    return new Promise((res) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            res(total = total + b);
        }, 1000);
    });
}
let res = arr.reduce(sumPromise, total);
res.then((a) => console.log(total));
```